# Why does this code hang during an insert of stl list

Tags: c++, stl

Why this code is hang during insert of `stl` list?
I have tried `copy` function also but it also not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std; 

class a{
    list<string> lista;

    public:
    a()
    {

        lista.push_back("ele");
        lista.push_back("phant");
        cout<<"End of Cons"<<endl;
    }

    list<string> getlist()
    {
        cout<<"Getting"<<endl;
        return lista;
    }
};

int main()
{

    a A1;

    list<string> list1;
    list1.insert(list1.end(),A1.getlist().begin(),A1.getlist().end());
    //copy(A1.getlist().begin(),A1.getlist().end(),back_inserter(list1));
    cout<<"End of Prog"<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Besides the answer by simonc, if you want to make sure the list is not modified, you should make the returned reference and the function `const` like in `const list<string>& getlist() const`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getlist` returns a list by value so `list1.insert` is using iterators into different lists for its start and end points.

You should change `getlist` to return a reference to its list rather than a copy of it

```
list<string>& getlist()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are returning a list from a function, using the declaration `list<type> getlist()`, It will not return the list that you are actually returning(`return lista`). Instead it makes a temporary copy of that list(lista) an returns that copy. So when you call getlist twice in your `insert` line, It will return the start and end iterator's of two different lists which creates an ambiguity.

So as @simonc suggested you need to change the declaration so that the copy is not done and an actual list is returned to the calling place.

Answer (score 0):

getList return a copy of list, which has its own memory address in iterator.